# Finding the query that is associated to a scheduled job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am new to sql server, we have sql server 2005 and have scheduled jobs running.
I want to know the query that is getting invoked when a scheduled job is run.
I have checked *job activity monitor->right click on the job->properties->steps*

I can see the name and type there, but cannot know what procedure is getting invoked and the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just click the 'Edit' button on the step, you will be taken to the step configuration screen. You can see what actions are being run on this screen.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Step edit screen]

Comment: Oh yeah, ignore that the 't-sql' is a load of rubbish, it was originally an SSRS command line step but I changed it to a T-SQL step for this example, which used the original command text :)

Comment: thank you for answering charleh, this is the command in the job activity monitor exec [dbo].[SP_SendAlert_DailyAtten], how can i find the code for this?

Comment: Do you know which database the job is running against? This is a stored procedure - look in Object Explorer (tree on left hand side of management studio) under <Database Name>->Programmability->Stored Procedures, you should find it there. Right click it choose 'Modify' or Script Stored Procedure as -> CREATE To -> New Query Window

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can run this query in Enterprise Manager:

```
use msdb
select j.name,step_id,step_name, command from sysjobsteps js inner join sysjobs j on js.job_id=j.job_id
-- where j.name LIKE '%blah%'
order by 1, 2
```